# Xcode 6 Autolayout Subview Constraints

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios8, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

Here's my storyboard.

[image: xcode 6 storyboard]

So you can see I made my main view background gray for debugging purposes. Inside that I have a view I call the 'Graph View' which is currently acting like a layout guide/container for a Chart (subclasses UIView). I've done constraints on the Graph View so it's (more or less) centered and has variable width/height depending on the device, seen in the Assistant Editor like so:

[image: assistant editor in storyboard preview mode]

I init the chart using the Graph View's `bounds.height` and `bounds.width` however that's going to be the size in the interface builder, which is 568x500.
After I init and configure the chart I want to add to the Graph View, I have the following code
in an attempt to give my chart subview the same layout/visual properties as the Graph View "guide":

```
lineChart.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
lineChart.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

[self.graphView addSubview:lineChart];

NSLayoutConstraint *width =[NSLayoutConstraint
                            constraintWithItem:lineChart
                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                            relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                            toItem:self.graphView
                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                            multiplier:1.0
                            constant:1];
NSLayoutConstraint *height =[NSLayoutConstraint
                            constraintWithItem:lineChart
                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                            relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                            toItem:self.graphView
                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                            multiplier:1.0
                            constant:1];
NSLayoutConstraint *top = [NSLayoutConstraint
                           constraintWithItem:lineChart
                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                           toItem:self.graphView
                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                           multiplier:1.0f
                           constant:0.f];
NSLayoutConstraint *leading = [NSLayoutConstraint
                               constraintWithItem:lineChart
                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                               toItem:self.graphView
                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                               multiplier:1.0f
                               constant:0.f];

[self.graphView addConstraint:width];
[self.graphView addConstraint:height];
[self.graphView addConstraint:top];
[self.graphView addConstraint:leading];

[self.graphView layoutIfNeeded];
[lineChart layoutIfNeeded];

[lineChart strokeChart];
```

The results are the following on the iPhone 5s and the iPad Air
[image: iPhone 5s Rendering]

[image: iPad Air Rendering]

I want the chart to fill the space of its container completely.. expand when in iPad and shrink when on the 5s.
Any idea what's wrong with my code?

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT**
Output from the Debug View Hierarchy iPhone 5s and iPad Air respectively.
[image: Output from Debug View Hierarchy iPhone 5s]
[image: Output form Debug View Hierarchy iPad Air]

Comment: Have you checked your view hierarchy with the new debugger tool in XCode ? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-debugger/using_view_debugger/using_view_debugger.html

Comment: I hadn't seen that new feature, thanks for the pointer. Threw a screenshot in my question.. Looks like the view is cropped, but the bottom labels are not.. iPad version is even weirder